# How to change pipeline run name depending on parameter in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Usually when you run a pipeline in Azure-pipeline you will see the Pipeline run number and commit message. We also have an option to deploy older build if you provide older build number in the parameter (Build number is not a github commit id but some sequential number generated during previous pipeline run). In this case, the commit message is confusing because we are not actually building latest code.

Can we disable commit message only when build number is provided in parameter? Can we add custom message in its place?

Following code is giving error. Looks like adding if-else at the top level doesn't work.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: manualVersion
    default: 'null'
    type: string

- ${{ if eq(parameters.manualVersion, 'null') }}:
  name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
- ${{ else }}:
  name: "Deploying manual version: ${{ parameters.manualVersion }}"
  appendCommitMessageToRunName: false
```

Error message: `While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set the name dynamically like

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: manualVersion
    default: 'null'
    type: string

variables:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.manualVersion, 'null') }}:
    - name: manualVersionDetail
      value: ""
  - ${{ else }}:
    - name: manualVersionDetail
      value: " Deploying manual version ${{ parameters.manualVersion}}"

name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)$(manualVersionDetail)
```

Reference: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-can-i-set-the-build-number-dynamically-with-conditions)

Using variables is not allowed in `appendCommitMessageToRunName`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points you need to pay attention to:

1. The '**`if...else`**' clauses are not available for '**`name`**' key in YAML pipelines.
2. The character '**`:`**' is not allowed to set the run (build) number. Remove or replace it with an allowed character (such as '**`-`**'). Also notice that the allowed max length of the run (build) number is 255 characters. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#faq).

   [image]

---

For your case, you can set your YAML like as below.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: manualVersion
  type: string
  default: 'null'

variables:
- name: setName
  ${{ if eq(parameters.manualVersion, 'null') }}:
    value: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
  ${{ else }}:
    value: "Deploying manual version - ${{ parameters.manualVersion }}"

name: $(setName)
```